# Detail text label of UITableViewCell is invisible till user touches it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I've got a UITableViewCell setup in a static & grouped tableView. The cell's style is subtitle and I'm setting it's initial value either like this (problem stays the same regardless of which I'm using):

```
self.myCell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f test", testFloat]];
```

or like this:

```
self.myCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"not set";
```

the detailTextLabel of the cell is invisible till I put my finger on it, I don't even have to release it, just lay it down on the cell so it becomes a little dark gray.

I've tried these two in viewWillAppear after I set my initial cell text, problem stays the same:

```
[self.myCell setNeedsLayout];
[self.myCell setNeedsDisplay];
```

Do any of you know why this is and how I can fix it?

Thanks a lot!

**Update:**

Label that displays correctly:

[image]

Label that displays incorrectly:

[image]

Comment: Update your question with the complete `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't have a cellForRowAtIndexPath method as my tableView is static

Comment: Check the color of the label and background color of cell, It might be possible that textColor and background color of text and cell is same. When you tap on the cell it will change to different color.

Comment: @deoKaushal I sat the color to red now, still the same issue :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known iOS 8 bug where the subtitle will not appear initially if it started off as nil.

If you ensure that `detailTextLabel` is never nil (or empty), even in Storyboard, it should always initially appear.

If you have some cells that won't have a subtitle, you'll need to set it to a blank space, instead of nil, or the issue will be triggered again.

(Apple introduced an "optimization" bug, where the label is removed its superview, if it does not appear to be used.  So, for the first layout pass, it gets added back too late to be properly sized, once you assign a non-nil string to it.  Interacting with the cell causes it to be highlighted, which is why the label appears correctly at that point.)